# How to set class JsonProperty

Tags: kotlin

I have this class here:

```
@Document
open class Product(){
  @Indexed(unique = true)
  @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
  var productKey: KeyClass = KeyClass(UUID.randomUUID())
    private set
}
```

In another class I want to write a function that sets a Product with a key like so:

```
myKey.forEach {item -> updateKey(Product(productKey = item.value)}
```

How can I write that logic in a correct syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that `productKey` is not a constructor parameter, that's why it can't be resolved by compiler for constructor invocation. You have 2 solutions.

1. Move `productKey` inside constructor block

```
open class Product(var productKey: : KeyClass) {
    // other stuff
}
```

then `Product(productKey = item.value)` will work as expected

2. Modify constructing of `Product` from

```
Product(productKey = item.value)
```

to

```
Product().apply { productKey = item.value }
```

**PS**: `private set` is useless in both cases. If you don't want `productKey` to be changed then just make it `val` not `var`.